# RxJava Android handling screen orientation change

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I have an Activity and a CompositeSubscription that is subscribed in onResule and unsubscribed in onPause. The app calls a login network request method using RxJava observable and subscribe to the returned Observable. How to handle a screen orientation change when the request is still executing. Currently, my Activity will unsubscribe from current subscriptions and my network call will not be delivered back to newly recreated activity.
Is there a way to serialize subscriptions objects to recreate them and be able to get the response from Observable?

Comment: If you have network request going on during orientation, use headless fragments. This might help : http://luboganev.github.io/blog/headless-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to cache all subscriptions in Application object and resubscribe from recreated activity.